# make monitor look exactly as tv for movies after enhancing colors

Tags: display, external-display

I was researching on tv vs monitor comparison and found that it is advised to use tvs for watching videos and movies because they provide better, enhanced colors that make movies look more realistic. Monitors just show whatever the computer asks it to show as it is. Tvs have some software which enhances colors.

So based on above understanding I was thinking would it not be possible to use software used by TVs for enhancing colors on our computer before outputting movies on monitor ? Off course TVs use some proprietry software but there is possibility to find some open source stuff which somewhat does the same thing.

Am I thinking right or did I miss something big here ? If I have missed something please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is something that really needs to be researched. You could simply try it out and see if you can notice a difference. Personally I'm quite happy to watch movies on my computer monitor. I don't find the monitor to be inferior in any way, other than size.

Comment: @user1751825 to me my 10 year old sony tv shows better than macbook pro inbuilt screen